# error TS2339: Property 'password' does not exist on type 'Document<any>'

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongoose

Me estoy encontrando un error, a la hora de realizar un schema para mongoose.
Como podeis ver a la hora de intentar acceder a password me dice un error, dice que password no existe en este tipo de Documento.
Aqui os dejo mi Schema completo

Es mi primer proyecto con Typescript cualquier cosa que se me esté escapando agradezco la respuesta,
me parece un lenguaje muy util pero complicado al principio

```
import mongoose, { Schema, Document } from 'mongoose'
import uniqueValidator from 'mongoose-unique-validator';
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';

export interface IUser extends Document {
    name: string;
    surname: string;
    age: number;
    email: string;
    password: string;
    date: Date;
    role: string;
    status: boolean;
    encryptPassword(password: string): Promise<string>;
    validatePassword(password: string): Promise<boolean>;
};

const role = {
    values: ['ADMIN', 'USER'],
    msg: '{VALUE} rol no valido'
};

const UserSchema: Schema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'El nombre es necesario'],
        lowercase: true
    },
    surname: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'El apellido es necesario'],
        lowercase: true
    },
    age: {
        type: Number,
        required: [true, 'La edad es necesaria'],
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Email obligatorio'],
        unique: true,
        lowercase: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        min: 6,
        required: [true, 'Contraseña obligatoria']
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    role: {
        type: String,
        default: 'USER', enum: role
    },
    status: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
    }
});

UserSchema.methods.toJSON = function() {
    const obj = this.toObject();
    delete obj.password;
    console.log(obj)
    return obj;
};

UserSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator, { msg: 'Error, esperaba {PATH} unico' });

UserSchema.methods.encryptPassword = async (password: string): Promise<string> => {
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    return bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
};

UserSchema.methods.validatePassword = async function (password: string): Promise<boolean> {
    return await bcrypt.compare(password, this.password)
}; 

export default mongoose.model<IUser & Document>('User', UserSchema);
```

[image]
Estos son los errores, justamente en donde quiero acceder al password, tambien ocurre que la funcion de encryptado de contraseña no está funcionando, entiendo que no este llegando la contraseña desde el Schema

Gracias a todos de antemano

Comment: podrías probar usando `mongoose.model<IUser>` ? IUser de por sí extiende Document, así que debiera ser innecesario el union type al final

Comment: Si, antes lo tenía de la manera que tu comentas, pero aún así, tampoco funcionaba. El problema viene cuando intentas acceder al password desde el this o desde la primera funcion despues del Schema, a la hora de intentar acceder al password de la constante que creamos objeto, me da error.

Answer (score 0):

No puedo asegurar que sea la solución, pero pienso que el problema está en que, si bien declaras la interfaz `IUser` que extiende `Document`

```
 export interface IUser extends Document {...}
```

Y luego procedes con la creación de un modelo cuyo Type Argument contiene `IUser`

```
 export default mongoose.model<IUser & Document>('User', UserSchema);
```

Ese modelo sigue siendo, al final, un documento y Mongo, por diseño, aceptará almacenar cualquier documento.

Faltaría añadir otra interfaz que utilice el template generic `Model` pasándole como type parameter la interfaz `IUser`, quedando:

```
 import mongoose, { Document, Model, Schema } from "mongoose";

 export interface IUser extends Document { /* lo mismo que tienes */ }

 export interface IUserModel extends Model<IUser> {}
```

así como IUser refleja documentos con la estructura de un usuario, IUserModel refleja las instancias del modelo que se crea con ese tipo de documentos.

Teniendo eso, podrías decirle a los métodos de la instancia que tal instancia es un `IUserModel`:

```
UserSchema.methods.toJSON = function(this: IUserModel) {
    const obj = this.toObject();
    delete obj.password;
    console.log(obj)
    return obj;
};

UserSchema.methods.validatePassword = async function (
    this: IUserModel,
    password: string
): Promise<boolean> {
    return await bcrypt.compare(password, this.password)
}; 

export const UserModel = mongoose.model<IUser>('User', UserSchema);
```

Si bien la interfaz Document, sin type parameter, no tiene atributo password ni método `toObject`, la instancia de `IUserModel` sí debiera tenerlos.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por la molestia, al final encontré otra manera de hacerlo. Pero voy a volver al codigo y voy a mirar esto que me pasas, gracias por tu tiempo y por tu ayuda amigo.

Comment: @AbrahamMenéndezGonzález Cuál fue tu solución